# Limiting results to a distinct column with SQL

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to get a list of items along with the order information for each item.  An order always has at least 1 item associated with it.  I want to limit this list to all of the items from 10 **orders**.  As my query stands below, it gets 10 **items**.  What is the best way to LIMIT this to 10 orders, while grabbing all of the items associated with these orders (be it 10 rows or 200 rows)?

```
SELECT o.*, i.*
FROM orders o, items i
WHERE i.order_id = o.id
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Much thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a subselect where you limit the orders first. In the outer select you then can fetch all items to these 10 orders.

```
SELECT o.*, i.*
FROM items i, (SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 0, 10) o
WHERE i.order_id = o.id
```

Comment: First and simplest answer - you get the check.  I hadn't thought of using a subselect in this way, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT oo.*, i.*
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM orders o
  LIMIT 10
  ) oo , items i
WHERE i.order_id = oo.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know mysql but to take a guess

```
SELECT o.*, i.*
FROM orders o, items i
WHERE i.order_id = o.id and 
o.id in (select o.id from orders o limit 0, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT o.*, i.*
FROM items i INNER JOIN orders o ON o.id = i.order_id
WHERE o.order_id IN (
  SELECT o.id
  FROM orders
  LIMIT 0, 10
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT orders1.*, items.*
FROM
(select * from orders 
LIMIT 10) AS orders1
LEFT JOIN items ON orders1.id = items.order_id;
```